# Adding sort icon in react

Tags: reactjs

i have created a method renderSortIcon in which i want to render an icon in this method i have passed a parameter column but when i do column.path it through me error path is no defined but when i do console.log it shows path
[image]

here is my code

```
class TableHeader extends Component {
  raiseSort = path => {
    const sortColumn = { ...this.props.sortColumn };
    if (sortColumn.path === path)
      sortColumn.order = sortColumn.order === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
    else {
      sortColumn.path = path;
      sortColumn.order = "asc";
    }
    this.props.onSort(sortColumn);
  };

  renderSortIcon = column => {
      // console.log(column.path)
      const {sortColumn} = this.props

    if (column.path !== sortColumn.path) return null;
    if (sortColumn.order === "asc") return <i className="fa fa-sort-asc" />;
    return <i className="fa fa-sort-desc" />;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {this.props.columns.map(column => (
            <th
              className="clickable"
              key={column.path || column.key}
              onClick={() => this.raiseSort(column.path)}
            >
              {column.label} {this.renderSortIcon(column)}
            </th>
          ))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    );
  }
}

export default TableHeader;
```

and this is columns array

```
columns = [
    { path: "title", label: "Title" },
    { path: "genre.name", label: "Genre" },
    { path: "numberInStock", label: "Stock" },
    { path: "dailyRentalRate", label: "Rate" },
    {
      
      key: "like",
      content: movie => (
        <Like liked={movie.liked} onClick={() => this.props.onLike(movie)} />
      )
    },
    {
      key: "delete",
      content: movie => (
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(movie)}
          className="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      )
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw your path was rendered twice, Im afraid if the first render is undefined, thus it return error.

To solve this error you may add this to your function:

```
renderSortIcon = column => {
  
  const {sortColumn} = this.props

if (column?.path !== sortColumn?.path) return null;
if (sortColumn?.order === "asc") return <i className="fa fa-sort-asc" />;
return <i className="fa fa-sort-desc" />;
};
```

Comment: why we are using  ? this

Comment: Its optional chaining, optional chaining syntax allows you to access deeply nested object properties without worrying if the property exists or not. If it exists, great! If not, undefined will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path is not YET available. Try to check if it exists first like:

`column.path ? column.path : 'something else if path is not there'`